# Do attendants of yama mistakenly kill wrong people due to the confusion in names?

Tags: mahabharata, death, yama

When I read Mahabharatha in Telugu, I came across a conversation between Uma and Siva. In the conversation, Siva says that sometimes the attendants of Yama take the wrong jiva to hell mistakenly. It is due to the ambiguity of the name and person mapping.

It means that if two women have the same name, then Yama dootas rarely commits the mistake of taking one woman (Jiva) to hell instead of another woman. Siva further says that although attendants of Yama commit a mistake, Yama never commits a mistake and sends the jiva again into her body. In that way, sometimes, Jivas may regain their life immediately after their death.

When I search for the conversation between Uma and Siva from [here](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b105.htm) to [here](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b113.htm). I didn't encounter such an answer from Siva. Since I didn't do a complete search, I am wondering whether such an explanation of Siva is present in the Anusasana Parva. If not, do any other scripture or Mahabharatha itself contains the fact of regaining life due to the mistake by attendants of Yama?

Comment: yes, correct. this is why sometimes you hear about people having 'near-death experiences', and 'out-of-body floating', and why some people are revived by CPR after getting heart attack. I have heard same in Tamil upanyasams too.